# Api to Implementation - can't compile firebase project anymore because of different versions

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I have a main app and a module that wraps all my firebase relevant code.

Problem I have is, that as soon as I change my firebase dependencies from `api` to `implementation`, I can't compile my project anymore. My main project build fails with following error:

**Error**

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDevDeDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core' has different version for the compile (9.0.0) and runtime (11.8.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

**My main app looks like following:**

```
dependencies {

    implementation project(':module-firestore')

    // NO OTHER FIRESTORE IMPORTS; NOT HERE NOT IN ANY OTHER MODULE!
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My firebase module looks like following:**

```
dependencies {

    // ----------------------
    // Firebase
    // ----------------------

    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${versions.playServices}"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${versions.playServices}"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${versions.playServices}"
    api "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:${versions.playServices}"

    // ----------------------
    // Firebase UI
    // ----------------------

    implementation ('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
}
```

**Global property**

```
ext {
    versions = [supportLib: "27.1.0",
                playServices: "11.8.0"]
}
```

Comment: what is `versions.playServices`

Comment: a global property set to `11.8.0`. I added this info to my question